# Incorrect text alignment in settings page

Tags: bug

I was just browsing through the settings page of my profile, when I noticed an incorrect text alignment in the ‘Tag Watching and Ignoring’ tab. The two different text, ‘Add tag’ and ‘Done’ have no space between them which makes it a bit difficult to click them. Here is a screenshot of the same:
[image]

I am using Safari 16.6.